# Is there a way to search a child entity table and check if each entity has a parent?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Group (Parent Object) and a GroupImage (Child Object) with a One to One mapping. I have Cascade set to ALL.

My problem is that every time I delete a Group, the corresponding GroupImage is deleted. This is fine until a Group with the standard no-group-image foreign key to a GroupImage entity gets deleted. This then means that any other groups using the standard image will have no GroupImage object leading to a NPE.

A solution I have thought of would be to not have the child entity (GroupImage) be deleted when a Group is, but to have a script run automatically every X amount of time to check the GroupImage table for any GroupImage without a parent (Group) object.

My question is, is it possible to check whether a child entity has a parent entity either through MySql or Java? Also how do I create the Group - GroupImage relationship so that the related GroupImage object is NOT deleted when the Group is?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but wouldn't it be way more simpler to create one image per group by default with the "no image" image (so you have a one to one relationship between groups and images) instead of having multiple entities referencing one "default" entity? Because then you could just delete the image if the group has been deleted or replace the image if one sets an actual image instead of the default one.

Comment: If several groups have the same image, then it's a many to one, not a one to one. To avoid deletion of the image, just don't use Cascade=all.

Comment: @Smutje I like this suggestion. Could be a case of me overcomplicating something again!! I will try it and report back with results. Thanks